# Could not save data in CoreData swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to save data in **CoreData**. When the app is running everything is ok. I receive info that data is saved and receive messages that it is fetching correct. But when I close the app data just disappeared somewhere.

When I created the project I do not check **Core Data**, so I added **xcdatamodel**, import **CoreData** everywhere, updated **AppDelegate** with the correct **NSPersistentContainer** name (the name is name of my xcdatamodel) also in Project-General-Frameworks added **CoreData.framework**.

Here is part of saving, fetching, and deleting data. The file is separate from VC. I do not receive any type of errors.

In my VC I just call **savedata()**, to save the data. It works before the app is closed.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var cgsTeams = [TeamsCoreData]()

func savedata() {
        saveTeams { (complete) in
            if complete {print("TeamsSaved")}
        }
}

func saveTeams(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {return}
    let privateManagedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateManagedContext.parent = managedContext
    
    
    
    for team in teams {
        let teamsCoreData = TeamsCoreData(context: privateManagedContext)
        teamsCoreData.team = team.name
        teamsCoreData.score = Int32(team.score)
        teamsCoreData.number = Int32(team.number)
        
        do{
            try privateManagedContext.save()
            debugPrint("Succesfully saved teamsCoreData")
            completion(true)
        } catch{
            debugPrint("Could not save - \(error)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}

func fetchTeams(completion: (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<TeamsCoreData>(entityName: "TeamsCoreData")

    do {
        cgsTeams = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("cgsGameRules fetched")
        teams = [team]()
        for cgsTeam in cgsTeams {
            print("team - \(cgsTeam.team!) added")
            teams.append(team(name:cgsTeam.team!, number: Int(cgsTeam.number), score: Int(cgsTeam.score)))
        }
        if cgsTeams.count > 1{completion(true)} else {completion (false); print("No teams")}
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(false)
    }
    
    
}

func deleteTeams(){
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<TeamsCoreData>(entityName: "TeamsCoreData")
    
    let objects = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for obj in objects {
        managedContext.delete(obj)
    }

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("error on delete Team")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call save() on your main managed object context somewhere, do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save changes in Core Data, the context saves only to its parent context. If it doesn't have a parent context, it saves changes to the persistent store file. You're saving changes on `privateManagedObjectContext`, which is a child context of `viewContext`. But you're never saving changes on `viewContext`. So your child context is telling the parent context about the changes, but the parent never saves those changes anywhere.

You need to either (a) save changes on `viewContext`, or (b) make `privateManagedObjectContext` its own stand-alone context, not a child context.